# ToolTwist port blocked from outside machine

Tags: tooltwist

I've got ToolTwist Designer deployed on port 37080 on a Linux server.

I can't access the Designer from my browser, and I can't telnet to the port from my machine:

```
$ telnet 11.22.33.44 37080  
Trying 11.22.33.44...  
telnet: connect to address 11.22.33.44: Connection refused  
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

However, I can telnet to the port when logged into the server:

```
$ telnet localhost 37080  
Trying 127.0.0.1...  
Connected to localhost.  
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Any ideas why this port can't be accessed from my browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to ensure that the Linux firewall (iptables) is not blocking any access. Here are some commands to check

```
/bin/iptables -L
```

and if blocked, then open access to that port. If you need Port 80 to forward to Port 37080 then these are the commands.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 37080
```

Run below to save the config so that it is saved for a system power cycle.

```
cd /etc/sysconfig
cp iptables iptables.prechange
iptables-save > iptables
service iptables restart
```